# Change android Ripple effect center position for android Appcompat radio button

Tags: android, radio-button, android-appcompat

I tried to make RTL radio -Put radio on right side- button for android with AppCompactRadioButton, and i achieved this with `android:drawableRight` and set `android:button="@null"` so my final view is what i wanted and final code is this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_man"
            style="@style/app_font"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/edit_text_height"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:button="@null"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/form_radiobutton"
            android:minHeight="33dp"
            android:onClick="onSexRadioButtonClicked"
            android:text="@string/hint_man" />
```

[image: wrong ripple on radio button]

But my question is how to to change ripple effect center position, because i set button to null, the ripple effect center poisiton is in center of radio button like image above and its not expected by user to see ripple there. i tried to set layout_direction to RTL, but nothing fixed.

I have to mention that i also tried to fix this problem with ripple drawable like below but nothing changed and problem is still there.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:color="@android:color/transparent">
<item>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item
            android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_activated"
            android:state_checked="true" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_deactive" />
    </selector>
</item>
</ripple>
```

Long story short, is there any idea to change android Ripple effect center position for android Appcompat radio button?

Comment: could you find a solution ?

Comment: @ReZa no, I didn't find any solution

Answer (score 5):

I can succesfully erase the ripple effect by changing the background of the RadioButton to transparent like this:

```
  android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

I didn't yet tried but i guess you can set a drawable with left padding to overcome this problem.

Comment: didn't find any solution yet, best answer till now is to remove the ripple effect...

Comment: Appreciate, that attribute helped.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is

`android:background="?selectableItemBackground"`

in your RadioButtons. That will overwrite the wrong ripple effect.